# Using the ProcessCmdKey function in VB.NET is leaving a character in the object

Tags: vb.net

Below is my code for ProcessCmdKey.

```
Public Class EmployeeStatus

    Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
        Handl(msg, keyData, bNavi)
    End Function

    Public Function Handl(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys, ByRef bNavi As BindingNavigator) As Boolean
        Try
            If keyData = (Keys.Control or Keys.S) Then
                TBSave
                Return True
            end if
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Function TBSave() as Boolean
        Try
            'Some code for saving to database
        Catch ex As Exception
            msgbox(ex.message)
        End Try
    End Function

End Class
```

Everything works fine except when it focused on textbox. It leaves character "S" in the object. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Whould you mind showing the complete code? Are you using some kind of `UserControl`?

Comment: yes, i used a usercontrol..it has a label and textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out... I just assign a blank string to the `msg` variable and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce it with the 1st code block. When you say `it leaves character "S" in the object` do you mean it leaves S the textbox?

If the ProcessCmdKey method returns true it has [processed the command key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However in your edit your calling `Handl` and **not returning its result *true*, just add the Returns keyword to fix it**:

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    Return Handl(msg, keyData, bNavi)
End Function
```